# Track number of swaps and comparisons in selection sort

Tags: c++, function, insertion-sort

I need to be able to track the number of exchanges and comparisons in this selection sort algorithm. The algorithm sorts the array just fine. I need to modify it in order to have tracked the number of exchanges.

```
void insertion_sort(int * theArray, int size)
{
   int tmp;
   for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) 
   {
        for (int j = i; j > 0 && theArray[j - 1] > theArray[j]; j--) 
        {
        tmp = theArray[j];
        theArray[j] = theArray[j - 1];
        theArray[j - 1] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the two helper functions

```
bool inOrder(int i, int j) {
   numComparisons++;
   return i <= j;
}


void swapElement(int & i, int & j) {
    int t = i;
    i = j;
    j = t;
    numSwaps++;
}
```

Comment: Don't you succeed to match which part of your code does equivalent to the helper function ?

Comment: Btw, I would just template the sort, and create a specific type which count swap(or affectation)/comparison...

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
void insertion_sort(int * theArray, int size)
{
   int tmp;
   int count = 0;
   for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) 
   {
        for (int j = i; j > 0 && theArray[j - 1] > theArray[j]; j--) 
        {
        tmp = theArray[j];
        theArray[j] = theArray[j - 1];
        theArray[j - 1] = tmp;
        count++; // increment on each loop/exchanges
        }
    }
}
```